# in java ,why writing file costs more time than reading file

Tags: java, io, operating-system

I test writing and reading in Java. Test code as below:

```
    @Test
    public void test_files(){
        File file = new File("a.txt");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
                bytes[i] = 1;
            }

            long l = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1024*100; i++) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
                fileOutputStream.flush();
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-l);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_read_files(){
        File file = new File("a.txt");
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            long i;
            while ( (i = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1){
                inputStream.read(bytes);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

test_files costs about 750ms except create for bytes.
test_read_files costs about 140ms.

I want to know what makes the difference. What java writing does cost so much time.

Comment: 1. Because you aren't using a buffered output stream. 2. Because you are flushing inside the loop, which would negate the buffering even if you had it. This is not practical code. Try it all again with buffered streams for both reading and writing, and no flushing.

Comment: With flushing out of the loop, time costs still the same about 741ms. I mainly want to know, compare reading and writing files in java , why writing costs more ,does it just write to pagecache or will sync to the disk.

Comment: With a buffered output stream, time shorts to 142ms.Seems I need to learn the difference between normal stream and the buffered stream.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It means java will synchronously write file to the disk? Otherwise, I test different buffer size, on my machine 64k is the best size, what will affect the buffer size performance.